# Comparing previous to current build in Jenkins CI

Tags: testing, jenkins, continuous-integration

We have software that builds a sqlite database regularly (outside of Jenkins).  I would like to run some tests to see if any tables in the current build are significantly smaller than in the previous build.  I think that I will simply need to serialize a result to disk (or database) and manually check for differences.  Is there some more formal framework in Jenkins to deal with this situation?

Comment: You could run a script from Jenkins that performs your desired check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to add a simple script to be executed by Jenkins or embed one in your build process to export a file that later can be used by [Measurement Plots Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Measurement+Plots+Plugin). This plugin can parse an XML file with your data, keep the history for more than one build and plot a graph for you. Although it will require some manual work it's the best option for things like that.

Comment: +1 - nice pragmatic solution that doesn't sound like it would require too much effort.

Comment: As for 2019 the Plugin Link says No information for the plugin 'measurement-plots' is available. It may have been removed from distribution.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2019 I still did not found a plugin that makes such a task easy

Here a rather pragmatic approach:

Usually buildlogs can be accessed view web with the pattern
JENKINSHOST:8080/job/%JOBNAME%/%BUILDNR1%/consoleText

With Powershell you can do something like

```
mkdir LOGS
powershell.exe (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://JENKINSHOST:8080/job/%JOBNAME%/%BUILDNR1%/consoleText', 'LOGS\%JOBNAME%-%BUILDNR1%.log')
```

It should be easy to generate a general purpose batch (or shell script using wget instead of powershell) that in the end
compares the two locally generated/downloaded outputs

'LOGS\%JOBNAME%-%BUILDNR1%.log'

and

'LOGS\%JOBNAME%-%BUILDNR2%.log'

with your favourite diff tool.

BTW:

If I where fit in plugin programming I would start looking to https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/JobConfigHistory+Plugin as template.